# Implement Searchbar to firebase recyclerview to search for nodes android studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to implement a search bar which will search the nodes and not the child. I've been able to achieve search if a node has a child then performing query and searching the value of the particular child. I'm not able to implement the same to search for the node value. Could anyone please help me know if this is possible an if yes how to go about it?

The code I'm using for implementing a search bar based on child value is

```
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Contacts> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Contacts>()
            .setQuery(UsersRef.orderByChild("username").startAt(search).endAt(search + "\uf8ff"), Contacts.class)
            .build();
```

With this code I'm able to search the database by entering the usernames in the search bar.

I woold like to achieve the search function based on node, i.e. when I enter the value of node in the searchbar, the query should return that particular node. Is that possible?

Comment: may I know what do you mean by node value?

Comment: WHat do you mean through node value? Please show us your database structure and indicate the exact data you want to get. Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: I was referring to the key of the object. @sanoJ has shown below how to achieve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use orderByKey() method to query by the node value(Assuming you're using node value to mention the key of the object).

```
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Contacts> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Contacts>()
        .setQuery(UsersRef.orderByKey().startAt(search).endAt(search + "\uf8ff"), Contacts.class)
        .build();
```

Comment: Thank you @sanoJ this is exactly I was looking for.